# Disable Bootup Scripts During OS Build

Tags: linux, bluetooth, boot

I'm working with a micro controller using Linux (probably Debian flavor). This controller will end up communicating via bluetooth and wifi with a phone.

I want to speed up the boot-up sequence and so I want to remove the non-essential startup sequences (such as printer, scanner, screen scripts).

The boot up scripts are found in `/etc/init.d`. And I know I can disable them via the command line using `update-rc.d someScript disable`. But I am compiling the OS and the kernel from scratch and I want these scripts to be disabled by default during the build procedure.

One way to do this is to simply delete these files from `/etc/init.d`. But how can I keep these files and still disable them by default during the compiling?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the executable bit from the scripts using `chmod -x script`. Correct way is of course using update-rc.d, but this should work too.

Comment: Thanks. But what you suggested is used when you boot up your system. What I want to do is build the OS from the source file and clone it to an SD card. During this build process, I want to remove the unnecessary build scripts. Basically, I want the OS to already be ready to go the very first time somebody turns it on!